# Can chrome phone emulators be trusted ?

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design

When developing and testing a websites responsiveness, is it wise to use chromes built in phone emulators to accurately do so?

Comment: I suggest you go through the `console.log` errors and fix each one. On my device, I got at least 15. You also have some responsive warnings. This is likely based on the way you're using and loading your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but it could be one of these things.

### Browser Cache

You may have made a change to that specific element in the past (fixed it) - but because of your browser's cache, it looks the same. Try clearing the cache on your device and see what happens.

### Script Issues

There is a chance that the scripts you're using to make the arrow go up and down are a bit too much for the mobile device, and make it behave in a weird manner. Perhaps leaving it still on mobile or removing it all together would be the solution?

**Edit:** After looking through the errors on the website, it seems like you have quite a few errors and some critical warnings. If you patch these up, it might work on mobile.

If neither of these are a solution, let me know in the comments below.

Comment: How could it be Browser Cache if they say *"BUT when I checked the site on my actual phone"*? It implies they didn't open it on their *"actual phone"* before, they only did it in an emulator (or anything not actual phone). And *"Script Issues"*? Why not *"Software"*? Or *"Technical problems"*? You're in a community of programmers, Jacob. Everything here is *"Script Issues"*. In order to provide answers you're supposed to know them. When you are *"not sure what the issue is"*, it is better ***not to answer***. Please see [answer] for details.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Good point with the cache. He likely was using an emulator for most of it. The reason I included it was because he could've checked it in the last update or so. As for the *"Script Issues"* - I'm surprised. JavaScript is a scripting language, is it not? You clearly have a background in such things (on your profile) and should know this is perfectly valid.  At this point, you just sound petty. In short, my answer was this. "If it isn't the cache, it is the *scripts*." Because I don't know which, I said: "I'm not sure what the issue is." Feel free to prove me wrong though.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a di*ck expecting you guys to solve the problem for me. I'm a fairly new programmer , so I feel I'm just constanstly in a "no idea what I'm doing" phase.

Comment: Anyways, I tried stopping the animation on mobile and nothing, but thank you Jacob for the replies ! As you said , I have a lot of critical js errors, so I'll probably try to sort those out, then see if that solves the problem (:

Comment: I know my previous comment wasn't very friendly and I apologize for that. Admittedly, this question could have been a lot better formulated, it would have been a lot better if it included a [mcve] (other than the link to a website - which will eventually get fixed, thus no longer displaying the problem so it could help future visitors). However, none of the above are valid excuses for post the above answer which, in fact, is not an actual answer to the question being asked. It's, at best, an extended, helpful comment and should have been posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your website seems to be a simple case of not loading CSS. Namely, you're trying to load `/assets/css/app.css` which appears to be missing (404).

Additionally, to fix the arrow's positioning, you'd need

```css
#hero {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```